# Dynaconf overwrites sections at settings.toml with .secrets.toml

Tags: python

I am using Dynaconf (3.1.2) to handle my python application settings.

If I use the same key at `settings.toml` and at `.secrets.toml`, the sections have at the end only the values from the secrets file and no more from the settings file. How can I handle this?

I have the following settings:

```
# settings.toml
[smtp]
host = "mail.myserver.com"
port = 587
username = "me@myserver.com"
```

```
# .secrets.toml
[smtp]
password = "mysecretpassword"
```

When I try to get settings.smtp.host I get the following exception:

```
dynaconf.vendor.box.exceptions.BoxKeyError: "'DynaBox' object has no attribute 'HOST'"
```

While debugging the settings object can be seen:

```
'SMTP': <Box: {'password': 'mysecretpassword'}>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to allow merge. Dynaconf will overwrite the configuration as the files as loaded. In your case, the contents of `settings.toml` will be overwritten by `.secrets.toml` as it is loaded after `settings.toml`.

To avoid this, you can enable `dynaconf_merge`.

```
# settings.toml
[smtp]
host = "mail.myserver.com"
port = 587
username = "me@myserver.com"
```

```
# .secrets.toml
[smtp]
dynaconf_merge = true
password = "mysecretpassword"
```

This will merge your `smtp` object from `.secrets.toml` to `settings.toml` and will not overwrite.

You can also enable a global merge like

```
# .secrets.toml
dynaconf_merge = true
[smtp]
password = "mysecretpassword"
```

This will merge all objects in `.secret.toml` to objects with same name in `settings.toml`

Reference: https://www.dynaconf.com/merging/#local-configuration-files-and-merging-to-existing-data